# Attribute on="change:..." is not working in AMP if I use input file using android camera

Tags: amp-html, amp-bind

I have an AMP page with a form, it has an input type "file". When you select a photo the form is submitted. I use that to preview the image. It works fine in android and pc, but it fails in android if you choose to take a picture instead of select an image.

In my case, it appears when I click to upload in my android:
[image: Options from android]
If I click file, it works fine. If I click Camera, nothing happens when the pic is took.

The code is simple:

```html
<input type="file"
       name="image"
       id="image"
       tabindex="0"
       on="change:item-form.submit">
```

Is there a way to trigger "on=change" from Android camera? If not, is there a way to prevent that action for smartphones?

Comment: Please file a feature request for AMP: https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/new/choose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `input-debounced` or `input-throttled` :  Elements that fire input event same as `change` event

**input-debounced**

Fired when the value of the element is changed. This is similar to the standard `change` event, but it only fires when 300ms have passed after the value of the `input` has stopped changing.

**input-throttled**

Fired when the value of the element is changed. This is similar to the standard `change` event, but it is throttled to firing at most once every 100ms while the value of the `input` is changing.

[**For more information**](https://amp.dev/documentation/guides-and-tutorials/learn/amp-actions-and-events/#input-elements)